# Ejabberd 14.07: smack StreamManagementNotEnabledException

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have following configurations in my ejabberdctl.yml

```
port: 5222
module: ejabberd_c2s
max_stanza_size: 65536
shaper: c2s_shaper
access: c2s
starttls: true
certfile: "/home/AJ/ejabberd-14.07/conf/server.pem"
stream_management: true
max_ack_queue: 1000
max_resume_timeout: 600
max_stanza_size: 65536
resend_on_timeout: true
resume_timeout: 300
```

and I am also getting this during server connection:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2758654035' from='MYHOST' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'><stream:features>
<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
<mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
<mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
</mechanisms>
<register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/>
</stream:features>
```

But I am still getting :

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.sm.StreamManagementException$StreamManagementNotEnabledException
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1645)
```

And I am listening acknowledgement as below:

```
MyApp.getXmpptcpConnection().addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(message.getStanzaId(), new StanzaListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                            Log.e(TAG, "msg delivered!" + packet.getStanzaId());
                            chatDatabaseHelper.updateMessageStatus(packet.getStanzaId(), Constants.XMPP_MESSAGE_DELIVERED);
                            if (Chats.chatAdapter != null) {
                                Chats.updateChatStatus(packet.getStanzaId(), Constants.XMPP_MESSAGE_DELIVERED);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Edit: My connection configs are as follows:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        chatMessageListenerImpl = new ChatMessageListenerImpl();
        chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListenerImpl(getInstance());

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setServiceName(Constants.XMPP_SERVICE);
        config.setHost(Constants.XMPP_HOST);
        config.setPort(Constants.XMPP_PORT);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
        connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
        connection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);

        connection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
        connection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
        connection.setReplyToUnknownIq(true);
        connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(25000);
        ReconnectionManager manager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        manager.setFixedDelay(5);
        ReconnectionManager.setDefaultReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.FIXED_DELAY);
        manager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```

It was working fine till morning, I did a server restart today.

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: I was facing the same error, you try to update all the gradle compile files, it will remove the smack error

Comment: @RakshitNawani, No luck I just did clean and build again, also I am using latest Smack 4.1.7 API's.

Comment: I mean all the gradle files, I was getting this error because of using old google gradle files, so try to use all the updated gradle

Comment: @RakshitNawani, I am already using updated gradle build tools, which version fixed your issue and did you made any changes in ejabberd?

Comment: I was using com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0 instead of com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.0, because of this I was facing the smack error, but when I update the gradle it was working like a charm for me, hope it help for you

Comment: @RakshitNawani, Mine current version is 
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2
com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
I am not using play-service-plus, I am using firebase instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117032/discussion-between-a-j-and-rakshit-nawani).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you did not enable Stream Management in Smack.

See

- [XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagement(boolean)](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#setUseStreamManagement-boolean-)
- [XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(boolean)](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#setUseStreamManagementDefault-boolean-)
- [XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(boolean)](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#setUseStreamManagementResumption-boolean-)
- [XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(boolean)](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection.html#setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault-boolean-)

Comment: HI @Flow, I have added my configuration already, please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: As I said, you likely did not enable SM in Smack. At least you did not show any code where you do so.

Comment: Updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: In that case it appears that the server is not offering SM in <features/>. But can't say for sure since you didn't not show the relevant part in the XMPP trace. But anyway: You should never unconditionally try to add a StanzaIdAcknowledgedListener! Always check if SM has been enabled.

Comment: @Flow I have set stream management disable on my connection using `connection.setUseStreamManagement(false);`. but when i am trying to add `addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener` it will through same exception `StreamManagementException$StreamManagementNotEnabledException` how to solve it ? is it compulsory need to enable stream management when add `addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener` ?